# How can i generate custom IDs for objects in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please I want to give custom IDs to my database objects in Firebase but I don't now how to do it. Firebase creates default IDs for database objects which I don't want. I want to be able to assign my own IDs to objects or the child nodes of in the database for unique identification.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're adding the items to the database with something like:

```
ref.push().set("my value");
```

This generates a new unique key under `ref` and sets your value on it.

If you want to use you own key/name for the child location, add the item with:

```
ref.child("my key").set("my value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize ID of firebase object, but you can create another field with ID role.
ref.child("my_id").set("customize_id");
after that, using "Filter by key" to get exactly your object you want.

In our case: We need to have a user_id type Int and auto-increase, so we can't use default _id of firebase object, we create user_id ourself to solve this problem.